# React Native - Sliding up Panel does not work on android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Does Anyone knows why the panel is not showing on android when I click on the button?
I'm using [https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-sliding-up-panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHVpr.png) btw. Please feel free to tell me, if you have any other recommended sliding panel library.

```
const CCTVTab = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          marginTop: 30,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignContent: 'center',
        }}>
        <Button title="Show panel" onPress={() => _panel.show(300)} />
      </View>

        <SlidingUpPanel
          style={{borderTopLeftRadius: 10}}
          ref={c => (_panel = c)}>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              alignItems: 'center',
              borderTopRightRadius: 18,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 18,
            }}>
            <Text>Header</Text>
            <Text>Content</Text>
            <Button title="Hide" onPress={() => _panel.hide()} />
          </View>
        </SlidingUpPanel>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: you can try https://github.com/enesozturk/rn-swipeable-panel, however I think rn-sliding-up-panel should also work. Show some code how you have implemented it in your code, so that I will have more idea.

Comment: but I included what I've used for the panel part tho, do you the whole render ?

Comment: @Rajender Kumar I updated my questionr. I decided to try it out with simple panel on a blank page